# how to to assign a parent's variable from the parent's child?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

i want to pass the variable from parent to child .How Can i pass the Variable.Here i paste my code.AnyBody please guide me.Thanks in advance!

My Parent Class

```
public class PlayerStrobe_domaincheck extends Sprite
{
    private var myService:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    private var _loader:Loader;

    public function PlayerStrobe_domaincheck()
    {
        _loader = new Loader();
        var sourceId:String = loaderInfo.parameters.src;// I want to pass This Variable
        var some:StrobeMediaPlayback = new StrobeMediaPlayback(parentObject);// Access of undefined property parentObject(Error Message).
        some = new StrobeMediaPlayback(this);
```

}
    }

My Child Class

```
public class StrobeMediaPlayback extends Sprite
{
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var sourceId:String; //i want to access the the parent  variable(sourceId) here
    parentClass = parent;
    function Test():void
        {
                mediaContainer.addMediaElement(alert);
                            alert.alert("Error",parentClass.sourceId);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class PlayerStrobe_domaincheck extends Sprite
{
    private var myService:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    private var _loader:Loader;


    public function PlayerStrobe_domaincheck()
    {
        _loader = new Loader();
        var sourceId:String = loaderInfo.parameters.src;

        var some:StrobeMediaPlayback = new StrobeMediaPlayback(sourceId);

        new StrobeMediaPlayback(this);
    }
}



public class StrobeMediaPlayback extends Sprite
{
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var sourceId:String;
    parentClass = parent;

   public function StrobeMediaPlayback(sourceIdVariablePassed:String):void
    {
                mediaContainer.addMediaElement(alert);
                trace("Source ID "+sourceIdVariablePassed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly do it unless your variable in the parent is `public`

Then again, it is not really good code to do that, because then the child is constrained to be added to only your parent class and nothing else.

The best way would be to dispatch an event, and have the parent listen to that event. The event handler in the parent should change the variable in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can pass parent to child class

```
public class StrobeMediaPlayback extends Sprite
{
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var sourceId:String; //i want to access the the parent  variable(sourceId) here
    private var parentClass:PlayerStrobe_domaincheck;

    public function StrobeMediaPlayback(parent:PlayerStrobe_domaincheck)
    {
        parentClass = parent;
        trace("welcome");
    }   
    public function Test():void
    {
        trace(parentClass.sourceId);
    }
}
```

and when you construct your child from parent (for example) pass parent object as param like

```
var some:StrobeMediaPlayback = new StrobeMediaPlayback(parentObject)
```

and you definition of parent should be like this

```
public class PlayerStrobe_domaincheck extends Sprite
{
    private var myService:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    private var _loader:Loader;
    private var some:StrobeMediaPlayback; //update
    public var sourceId:String;

    public function PlayerStrobe_domaincheck()
    {
        _loader = new Loader();
        sourceId = loaderInfo.parameters.src;// I want to pass This Variable
        some = new StrobeMediaPlayback(this) //update
    }
}
```

you can defile your child object in parents constructor

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property sourceId through a reference with static type PlayerStrobe_domaincheck. am getting error like this sir

Comment: How do you define your child object? Have you correctly pass parent to it as parameter?